# Azure blob download Authorization resource type mismatch

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download a client's blob data which is in JSON format from their azure storage.

I have the account URL containing the SAS token, the SAS token itself as well as connection URL.

However, when I try to download a blob from their server, I am getting the following error :

```
This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
RequestId:d6d9d23e-301e-0078-32be-ecd22a000000
Time:2020-02-26T16:02:05.6188260Z
ErrorCode:AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch
Error:None
```

Here is the code I am using :

```
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

try:

    account_url = "account_url/sas_token"

    # Open the container containing the relevant blobs
    container = ContainerClient(account_url, container_name="container_name")

    # Printing the available blobs 
    blob_list = container.list_blobs()
    for blob in blob_list:
        print(blob.name + '\n')

    blob_client=container.get_blob_client("blob_name")

    print(blob_client)

    with open("./test.txt", "wb") as my_blob:
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
        blob_data.readinto(my_blob)


except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)
```

Any more information about this error would be appreciated ! 
Thanks :D

Comment: seems that the SaS token is invalid

Comment: I was thinking that too, I have emailed the client to ask about this but I posted here just in case there might have been anything else I missed. Thanks for the response 

Comment: double check if there's "sp=r&sr=b" in the SAS TOken where sp stands for permission and sr is resource (blob)

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Hmmm Looking at the SAS Token now, I see "sp=rdl&srt=c&ss=b" any idea what that combination describes ?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Thank you for your help ! It was indeed the Token that was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your objective is to download blob, please make sure that your `signed resource type (srt)` should include `object (o)`.

Your `srt` should be like `srt=co` (or just `srt=o`).

Please regenerate the SAS token accordingly.

You can see the Account SAS permissions by operations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas#account-sas-permissions-by-operation (Download Blob is basically Get Blob operation).

Comment: Currently my srt=c, I think the client created the token wrong. I will get in touch with them

Comment: Yep, I noticed. It should be `srt=o`.

Comment: Alright I got the new SAS token and it is working, thanks for the help !